# False frame in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, row-height

i am trying to implement a custom UITableVieCell into my TableView. Within the cell there are two subviews which are getting wrong properties.

Here is my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ListCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 70.0f)];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And here are the two init-methodes from my custom Cell ListCell:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.frame = frame;

        cellBack = [[ListCellBack alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        cellFront = [[ListCellFront alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];

        [self.contentView addSubview:cellBack];
        [self.contentView addSubview:cellFront];

        slideEnabled = YES;
    }
    return self;
}


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

That is the solution:

[image]

And that is my goal:

[image]

So the two subviews of my custom Cell are getting the wrong numbers of the frame.
I am struggling with this for hours!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you change the height for your cell in:
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return heightOfYourCell;
}

Comment: yes, i tried that too. I became the same result as above

Comment: I don't have one. I just add two subviews (uiviews) to the ListCell.
In my screenshots you can't see the second view because it is behind the first one. Therefore cellBack and cellFront

Comment: i dont know why you'r not you use xib file for your cell, its much more easier tu custom an manipulate your cell as you want ?

Comment: Would it make my situation better right now? Or is it just generally easier?

Comment: yes you can see this tutorial and you well be able to play with your cell as you want:
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Mhh not quiet what i expected, but hey it works! Thanks!